# How do I get Google Calendar's Day View back to a single wide column format?

Tags: google-calendar

Google Calendar was recently redesigned, and some of the changes reduced functionality & usability.

For example, I have subscribed to several other calendars so that their events appear on my calendar view, in other colors.  When I go to Week view, sometimes there are so many events that it's hard to see enough detail within a single day's column.  It used to be that I could fix this by clicking into Day view for that day, at which point the day would occupy the entire width and there would be plenty of space to show more event details.
However, with the redesign, the Day view is a multicolumnar format much like Week, except showing different calendars instead of different days of the week.  Most of these are empty or close to it, and the events I'm interested in disambiguating are all stuck together and hard to read just as before.  **How do I get something like that old Day view back?**

Answer (score 4):

Near the upper right corner, click the gear:
[image: Settings gear interface]

Choose "Settings" from the dropdown. A Settings page should load.

Scroll down to the "View options" setting and uncheck "View calendars side by side in Day View."

[image: Screenshot]